# how to enable the console login for IAM user in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am new to terraform created IAM user with below terraform file , but when see in aws console it says console login is not enable attached the image too, please help how to enable the password.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "lb" {

name = "${var.user_name}"

  # path = "/system/"
  # tags = {
  #   tag-key = "tag-value"
  # }
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "lb" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "lb_ro" {
  name = "test"
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }   
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "u" {
  user                    = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"
  password_reset_required = true
  pgp_key                 = "${base64encode(file("/Terraform_practice/iam_terra/oli.gpg.pubkey"))}"

  # pgp_key = "keybase:deekshithsn"
}

output "password" {
  value = "${aws_iam_user_login_profile.u.encrypted_password}"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXrA2.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hii i figured out the problem, to create an Iam user with console login enabled you need to install keybase on your operating system visit for more information

[Keybase Download](https://keybase.io/download)

Then you need to create a pgp key in you local secret keychain
using this command

```
keybase pgp gen
```

Then give the reference of this created key into your terraform file like this

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "/home/username/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "u" {
  name          = "terraform"
  path          = "/"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "u" {
  user    = "${aws_iam_user.u.name}"
  pgp_key = "keybase:your_keybase_username"
}

output "password" {
  value = "${aws_iam_user_login_profile.u.encrypted_password}"
}
```

then it do

```
terraform apply
```

then terraform will output the password in an encrypted form which needs to be decrypted with the following command

```
terraform output password | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt
```

i have tested this and its working fine let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed explanation . I followed the same steps but, if I see aws console

Comment: is terraform throwing any errors, can you paste the output of terraform command here

Comment: User got created but in aws , if I go to that users security information it says **User does not have console management access **

Comment: No its not throwing any error. User got created but , no console login. image I have attached with the post.
for you is the console login enabled ?

Comment: have you replaced the  pgp_key = "keybase:your_keybase_username" with your own keybase username in terraform file

Comment: and only this file is needed to successfully create an iam user on aws, are you using any code from your previous file ?

Comment: i'm glad it worked please upvote the answer if it helped you, thanks

Comment: sure I will do it , but as of now I might not able to do because I think should reach 15 reputations.

Comment: Is this still best practice in 2021? The terraform documentation [LINK](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_user_login_profile) is vague but still recommends keybase. then when I ran "keybase pgp gen" it asked my for 2+ email addresses, which seemed strange...

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do without using keybase. I was naively passing the key-id instead of the actual public key.

```
gpg --generate-key
gpg --export | base64 > public.gpg
```

Then in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "test-user" {
  user    = aws_iam_user.test-user.name
  pgp_key = file("public.gpg")
}

output "password" {
  value = aws_iam_user_login_profile.test-user.encrypted_password
}
```

To decrypt the password:

```
# Just read the password = "uuu" - but remove the spaces and "quotes"
# So you get a bash variable called `password`
export $(terraform output | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/"//g')
# Now read it
echo $password | base64 -d | gpg -d
```

*Edit:* I'm now using gpg with `gpg --expert --full-gen-key` and choosing ECC `secp256k1` all the way. I haven't tried this with terraform, but it generates smaller keys and messages than RSA and I expect it'll be more secure, because it's the same algorithm used with bitcoin.

Comment: can't seem to do the "read" part. it's giving me an invalid input. if i export (2nd to the last step) what it gives me is this bash: export `[myoutputvariablefromtf]=xxxxx': not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detailed info..

I got the error when i ran it, but below command works for me,

> *terraform output -json password | jq -r . | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt*

Answer (score 1):

If you get the Error as ***Invalid Input***, while you already have the passwords in tfstate file, you can copy that encrypted password and provide it to base64 command as input.
`echo "your encrypted password string here" | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt`

Answer (score 0):

I have that error:

```
ERROR loadme error: 
    API network error:
    Get https://api-0.core.keybaseapi.com/_/api/1.0/merkle/root.json?c=1&last=22086426&skip_last=1: net/http: 
    TLS handshake timeout
```

When I run that command:

```
echo "your encrypted password string here" | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt
```

What I must do ?